# Extract specific information from logs

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have extracted the following information from the raw logs below using this command:

`echo -e "Timestamp\t\tEmailTo:\t\tEmailFrom:\t\t\t\t\tIPAddress:\tErrorCodes:" && sed -n -e 's/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9]*\) .*\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1 \2 /p' logs`

Output:

```
Timestamp       EmailTo:        EmailFrom:                  IPAddress:  ErrorCodes:
2017-01-02 12:50:00 
2017-01-02 13:10:25
```

Raw logs:

```
2017-01-02 12:50:00 1cNxNS-001NKu-9B == redhat_619@yahoo.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp defer (-45) H=mta6.am0.yahoodns.net [98.138.112.38]: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<web@pharma.com> SIZE=1772: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 192.168.1.269 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html
2017-01-02 13:10:25 1cNxhD-001VZ3-0f == infopharma@yahoo.com (info@pharma.com) <info@pharma.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-45) H=mta7.am0.yahoodns.net [98.138.112.34]: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<red@nic.net.org> SIZE=87839: 500 5.9.0 [TSS04] Messages from 192.168.1.269 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html
```

But I am unable to extract the other information I need; it should looks like:

```
Timestamp            EmailTo:              mailFrom:            IPAddress:      ErrorCodes:

2017-01-02 12:50:00  redhat_619@yahoo.com  web@pharma.com       192.168.1.269   421 4.7.0
2017-01-02 13:10:25  infopharma@yahoo.com  red@nic.net.org      192.168.1.269   500 5.9.0
```

How can I extract all the information using `sed`?

Comment: What's exactly the problem you have with `sed` patterns? You just need to extend your current pattern to match the information you need, and not just the first two pieces.

Comment: I have tried to extend it further but unable to extract like i'm trying to extract third field using below command but not get successful result.
`sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9]*\) .*\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]*\) .\^([^==]\[A-Z0-9._%-+]\@[A-Z0-9.-]\.[A-Z]{2,4}*\).*/\1 \2 \3 /p' exim_logs
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `sed` expression:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.* .* \).* .*== \([^ ]* \).*MAIL FROM:<\([^ ]*\)> [^ ]* \([0-9 .]*\)\[.*Messages from \([^ ]*\).*$/\1\t\2\t\3\t\5\t\4/'
```

It works for me with your example.

#### Explanation

This `sed` expression contains only one command -- `s/.../.../`.

First part of `s///`:

```
'^\(.* .* \)'      -- Timestamp, two first space-separated blocks of text, \1.
'.* .*== '         -- Uninteresting text after timestamp.
'\([^ ]* \)'       -- Block of test between spaces, first email address, \2.
'.*MAIL FROM:<'    -- Position before second email.
'\([^ ]*\)>'       -- Second email addr, non-space characters, ended by '>', \3.
' [^ ]* '          -- SIZE=...:
'\([0-9 .]*\)\['   -- Error codes: digits, spaces and dots ended by '[', \4.
'.*Messages from ' -- Position before IP.
'\([^ ]*\)'        -- Non-space characters, ended by space, IP. \5.
'.*$'              -- Text before end of string, not interesting.
```

As you can see, it's just direct description of raw logs, there is nothing interesting.

Second part of `s///` is just placing `\N` in right order with `\t` (tab character) as a separator.

Comment: Thanks it works for me but please elaborate this command.

Answer (score 0):

I've not got much experience with awk, but thought I'd have a go. I imagine this is quite fragile as I dont know how many log lines you're trying to get with this.

Anyway, this uses the `BEGIN` block to set up the variables to pick out, and a format-string for printing before displaying the header. The time and EmailTo are predictable, so then can use the numbered fields (`$1`, `$2` and `$5`) before the three sets of regexps which are only very rough. Any suggestions to improve would be appreciated!

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        from=""; ip=""; error=""; fstr="%-24s%-24s%-40s%-16s%s\n";
        printf(fstr, "Timestamp:", "EmailTo:", "EmailFrom:", "IPAddress:", "ErrorCodes:");
    }
{   for (i=6; i<NF; i++)
    {   
    # From Address
    if ($i ~ /FROM:<[^ ]*>/)  
        from=substr($i, 7, length($i)-7);
    # Errors found in two adjacent fields.
    if ($(i-1) ~ /[[:digit:]]{3}/ && $i ~ /[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/)
        error=$(i-1) " " $i;
    # From address after predictable string.
    if ($(i-2) " " $(i-1) == "Messages from" && $i ~ /[[:digit:].]{7,15}/)
        ip=$i;
    }
    printf(fstr, $1" "$2, $5, from, ip, error);
}' logs
```